# Django - Dynamic number of ModelForms based on dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, forms

I have a form that registers teams of people. Based on a dropdown to select the number of members in the team, the form should show that many model forms, one for each member.

I am not particularly sure what the correct design patter for this is. Here are the solutions that I have come up with:

1. Use JS to generate the HTML for each member form and then use the Django ModelForm backend to parse each form. However, in this case I cannot use the inbuilt rendering functions of Django and validation notification becomes bothersome.
2. Send a GET request whenever the user changes the dropdown value, and the GET request specifies the number of members you want to add. But here it would result in any previously entered data being cleared.
3. Send a POST request via JS whenever the dropdown is updated, and then re-render the form with the appropriate values picked up from the POST request. I am not sure if this is the right way to do this and seems to be easy to get wrong.

Can you please advise on what is the best solution for this scenario?

I am pretty sure this has already been answered somewhere, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. If you have the link to the answer, please go ahead and mark this question as a duplicate.